# Remove AD user from domain and convert it to local admin account

Tags: windows-10, administrator, windows-domain

How can one convert a domain AD account to a local user account and then when I want, revert the same profile back into a domain account...? Thanks

Comment: You can't;  There is no process to convert a domain account into a local account. 
 You can create a local account and manually migrate files within the domain profile.  This would require you to modify the ACL of the profile directory as the domain user to include your local accounts.

Comment: I use a free software for all account moving and domain changing for profiles. Look up **ProfWiz** and this will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the AD account to the local admin group on the computer. The user will be able to continue to log in due to their cached credentials. You can add them to the local admin group as following:

1. Right Click on My Computer (make sure you have admin privileges)
2. Select Manage
3. Navigate through System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Groups *
4. On the Right-Side, Right Click on Administrators
5. Select Properties
6. Click the Add... button
7. Type the User Name of the user you want to add as local admin.
8. Click the Check Names button to verify the user name is correct.
9. Click the OK button
10. Click the OK button

Beyond that, the account swap you describe in your question cant be done.

Comment: Thank you Silbee. I managed to find a 3rd party app that allowed me to do what you suggested with ease. Moreover,  that is correct as well. Thank you for sharing your insight.